# Convert from absolute to relative path Python,make variable as final

Tags: python, path, relative-path, final

I have the below script:

```
    auto = '/home/amol/src/auto'
    autoqa = '/home/amol/src/autoqa' 

scripts = autoqa + '/auqa/scripts/'
```

I want to convert it into relative path

```
def getSrcDir():
    os.system('cd ../../../')
    os.chdir("../../..")
    return os.getcwd()
    srcDir=getSrcDir()
    print 'Src Dir is ',srcDir
    auto=srcDir+'/auto'
```

However there are some other python scripts that modify these values at run time.
Is there a way I can prevent the values of these variables from being overridden and make it final?.